# Simple SQLAlchemy query in Flask performs very slowly

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a table like this:

```
                             Table "public.transactions"
       Column        |           Type           | Nullable | Default | Storage  |
---------------------+--------------------------+----------+--------------------|
 id                  | integer                  | not null | nextval | plain    |
 ticket              | integer                  |          |         | plain    |
 pay_station         | character varying(50)    |          | extended|          |
 stall               | character varying(50)    |          |         | extended |
 license_plate       | character varying(8)     |          |         | extended |
 purchased_date      | timestamp with time zone | not null |         | plain    |
 expiry_date         | timestamp with time zone |          |         | plain    |
 payment_type        | character varying(50)    |          |         | extended |
 total_collections   | numeric(10,2)            |          |         | main     |
 revenue             | numeric(10,2)            |          |         | main     |
 rate_name           | character varying(50)    |          |         | extended |
 hours_paid          | numeric(4,2)             |          |         | main     |
 validation_revenue  | numeric(10,2)            |          |         | main     |
 transaction_fee     | numeric(10,2)            |          |         | main     |
 method              | character varying(50)    |          |         | extended |
Indexes:
    "transactions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "transactions_expiry_date_idx" btree (expiry_date)
    "transactions_purchased_date_idx" btree (purchased_date)
    "transactions_stall_idx" btree (stall)
```

And ~20 more columns I omitted for brevity.

This table has ~2.5 million rows.

Now my Python code in Flask which is serving an API looks like this for an example query:

```
filters = [
    datetime_range['start'] < Transactions.expiry_date,
    datetime_range['end'] > Transactions.purchased_date
]

if 'parking_spaces' in params:
    spaces = params['parking_spaces'] # array
    filters.append(Transactions.stall.in_(spaces))

results = Transactions.query.with_entities(
    Transactions.stall, Transactions.purchased_date, Transactions.expiry_date
    ).filter(*filters).order_by(Transactions.purchased_date).all()
```

Where the dates are `datetime` objects. Now, if I don't provide any input in the POST body, I default to a min/max time, no WHERE IN spaces, and the query looks like this:

```
datetime_range: 
{'start': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'end': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}

Query: 
SELECT transactions.stall AS transactions_stall, transactions.purchased_date AS transactions_purchased_date, transactions.expiry_date AS transactions_expiry_date 
FROM transactions 
WHERE transactions.expiry_date > %(expiry_date_1)s AND transactions.purchased_date < %(purchased_date_1)s ORDER BY transactions.purchased_date
```

Now, if I do the query directly in `psql`:

```
SELECT transactions.stall, transactions.purchased_date, transactions.expiry_date FROM transactions WHERE transactions.expiry_date > '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000Z' AND transactions.purchased_date < '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000Z';
```

**Time: 2724.326 ms (00:02.724)**

However, executing the same query in SQLAlchemy via Flask, using Postman to test, I get a response in **866946 ms (14:26.946)** returning 13.4KB of data.

Which is obviously a massive difference. As I adjust the range, the response time increases exponentially -- some samples:

```
{
    "datetime_range": {
        "start": "2017-01-01T14:30:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-01-04T18:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

**Response Time: 13387 ms (00:13.39)**

Same query in psql:

```
SELECT transactions.stall, transactions.purchased_date, transactions.expiry_date FROM transactions WHERE transactions.expiry_date > '2017-01-01T14:30:00.000Z' AND transactions.purchased_date < '2017-01-04T18:00:00.000Z';
```

**Time: 580.603 ms**

```
{
    "datetime_range": {
        "start": "2017-01-01T14:30:00.000Z",
        "end": "2017-03-01T18:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

**SQLAlchemy Response Time: 41878 ms**

```
SELECT transactions.stall, transactions.purchased_date, transactions.expiry_date FROM transactions WHERE transactions.expiry_date > '2017-01-01T14:30:00.000Z' AND transactions.purchased_date < '2017-03-01T18:00:00.000Z';
```

**PostgreSQL Response Time: 1170.169 ms (00:01.170)**

Why is there such a huge difference here, and how can I get SQLAlchemy to execute quicker and keep my Flask response times on the order of seconds, rather than minutes?

Comment: At least there's the difference that your SQLA query has an (implicit?) ORDER BY, where as your manual tests seem not to. Try adding that and see what happens. I guess it should not matter that much, since it is on indexed column, but still. All in all try double checking that your SQLA queries are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Good catch -- I actually had just copied another (but very similar) query from my Python code. I edited the question to have the right code which includes the intentional order_by. This query directly in psql: `SELECT transactions.stall, transactions.purchased_date, transactions.expiry_date FROM transactions WHERE transactions.expiry_date > '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000Z' AND transactions.purchased_date < '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000Z' ORDER BY transactions.purchased_date;` has a response time of 5457.151 ms (00:05.457) so slightly slower, but not 15 min, so it doesn't seem to be the issue here

Comment: It sounds like you might have some accidentally quadratic thing going on. What do you do before and after you get `results`? Can you try logging `datetime.now()` immediately before and after `results = ...`?

Comment: Hey @univerio, you ended up being largely on the mark. Don't know why I didn't think to do that immediately, but the actual query itself takes 30-60 seconds, with the rest of the code doing the brunt of the work afterwards, resulting in the insanely slow response time. I think the 30-60 seconds for the pure db call is still unacceptably slow, compared to ~5 seconds directly in Postgres as aforementioned, but this probably warrants a separate and more specific question. I'll leave this question up for others to double check the basics if they run into a similar situation